# Events handling between Spring boot and Reactjs

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, events, corda

This might seem like an easy solution got on the internet, but believe me, I have seen through a lot of examples and couldn't figure out which approach to choose.

**Requirement** :
I have a subscriber at the application service(spring boot/Java) end, subscribed to blockchain events( corda ). I want to push this event to UI (ReactJS) whenever there is a change in state.

I could subscribe to the blockchain events successfully but stuck with multiple in-complete or tangled ideas of pushing it to the UI and how UI would receive my events ( kindly don't suggest paid services, APIs, Libraries etc ).

I have come across and tried out all approach, since I'm newly working on events I need some ray of light as to how to approach towards a complete solution.

1. Publisher-subscriber pattern
2. Observable pattern
3. Sse emitter
4. Flux & Mono
5. Firebase ( a clear NO )

+**Boggler** :

1. events handling between service and UI , should it be via API/endpoint calls or can it be emitted just in air( i'm not clear) and based on event name can we subscribe to it in UI ?
2. should i have two APIs dedicated for this ? one trigger subscribe and other actually executes emitter ?
3. If the endpoint is always being heard doesn't it needs dedicated resource ?

I basically need a CLEAR approach to handle this.

***Code can be provided based on demand***

Comment: 1,2 and 4 are basically 3 or through websockets. How you do stuff on the server doesn't necessarily change how you do things on the client.

Comment: Not a React expert, but please have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/iou-reactfrontend-Braid) from the deprecated samples repo; it uses React for front-end; maybe you'll find some answers there.

Answer (score 1):

I see you mention you are able to capture events in Spring Boot. So you are left with sending the event information to the front-end. I could think of three ways to do this.

- Websockets: Might be an over-kill, as I suppose you won't need bi-directional communication.
- SEE: Perhaps a better choice than WebSockets.
- Or simply Polling: Not a bad choice either, if you are not looking for realtime notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Long Polling.

The solution seems to be pretty simple. Make the connection once and let them wait for as long as possible. So that in the meanwhile if any new data comes to the server, the server can directly give the response back. This way we can definitely reduce the number of requests and response cycles involved.

You will find multiple implementation examples of How Long Polling is done as part of Spring Boot project on internet.